# Intellij sbt won't resolve dependencies' dependencies

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have a Intellij Scala project, that depends on another lib, which in turn depends on some other libs (gson, log4j...), but somehow Intellij won't add those transitive dependencies to my project, so when I run my main method, jvm always complains no class found. I also tried `sbt update` and `sbt update-classifier`, they won't resolve down the dependency path as well. How can I have sbt resolve all levels of dependencies?

Comment: You can add transitive dependencies to it via SBT

Comment: I think sbt should do so by default, so something's not right with your setup - perhaps paste your `build.sbt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out what was wrong, it was the sbt-s3-resolver plugin I was using couldn't resolve maven style dependencies, I used an another plugin which supports maven libs and it worked. But I still couldn't figure out why it worked before.

Answer (score 0):

If all works in SBT command lines but not in Idea then remove the `.idea` folder and reload the SBT project in Idea.
I should warn that you will loose the project configs (such as run configs) by doing that.